# How to get the next hash element from hash?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have this hash:

```
HASH = {
  'x' => { :amount => 0 },
  'c' => { :amount => 5 },
  'q' => { :amount => 10 },
  'y' => { :amount => 20 },
  'n' => { :amount => 50 }    
}
```

How can I get the key with the next highest `amount` from the hash?

For example, if I supply `x`, it should return `c`. If there is no higher amount, then the key with the lowest amount should be returned. That means when I supply `n`, then `x` would be returned.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is your hash is already sorted by amount?

Comment: Yes. But I read somewhere that hashes cannot be sorted in Ruby. I might be wrong here, though.

Comment: @Tintin81 You can sort hashes in ruby.  Hash uses the enumerable module to give `sort` and `sort_by` methods

Comment: They cannot be sorted, but they can (from version 1.9) have an order, so you can create a new hash with the new order if you want it sorted.

Comment: By the way, this is a nice link I just found on how to sort nested hashes: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to/ruby-sort-hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
def next_higher(key)
  amount = HASH[key][:amount]
  sorted = HASH.sort_by { |_, v| v[:amount] }
  sorted.find(sorted.method(:first)) { |_, v| v[:amount] > amount }.first
end

next_higher "x" #=> "c"
next_higher "n" #=> "x"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
def find_next_by_amount(hash, key)
  sorted = hash.sort_by { |_, v| v[:amount] }
  index_of_next = sorted.index { |k, _| k == key }.next
  sorted.fetch(index_of_next, sorted.first).first
end

find_next_by_amount(HASH, 'x')
# => "c"

find_next_by_amount(HASH, 'n')
# => "x"
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you. Unless someone comes up with an even shorter version, I will mark this one as the correct answer.

Comment: Note that this always returns the next key, even if the amounts are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
def next(key)
  amount = HASH[key][:amount]
  kv_pairs = HASH.select{ |k, v| v[:amount] > amount }
  result = kv_pairs.empty? ? HASH.first.first : kv_pairs.min_by{ |k, v| v}.first      
end
```

I'm curious, why would you want something like that? Maybe there is better solution to underlying task.

EDIT: Realized that hash isn't necessary sorted by amount, adapted code for unsorted hashes.

Comment: @toro2k you get a `SyntaxError` because you are invoking the [`next` statement](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-next+Statement)  outside of a loop, not because of the method name. Calling `self.next(0)` or `send(:next, 0)` would work, but of course, no sane developer would use `next` as a method name :-)

Comment: wait, where's your comment?

Comment: @Stefan I realized it was not completly right the moment before you posted yours and I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
A = HASH.sort_by { |_,h| h[:amount] }.map(&:first)
  #=> ['x', 'c', 'q', 'y', 'n']
```

(If `HASH`'s keys are already in the correct order, this is is just `A = HASH.keys`.)

```
def next_one(x)
  A[(A.index(x)+1)%A.size]
end

next_one 'x' #=> 'c'
next_one 'q' #=> 'y'
next_one 'n' #=> 'x'
```

Alternatively, you could create a hash instead of a method:

```
e = A.cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["x", "c", "q", "y", "n"]:cycle> 
g = A.size.times.with_object({}) { |_,g| g.update(e.next=>e.peek) }
  #=> {"x"=>"c", "c"=>"q", "q"=>"y", "y"=>"n", "n"=>"x"}
```

Comment: This looks really cool too. Thank you. I am starting to realise that there are many answers to my question.

Comment: Entry Order
A Hash object presents its entries in the order of their creation. This is seen in:

Iterative methods such as each, each_key, each_pair, each_value.

Other order-sensitive methods such as shift, keys, values.

The String returned by method inspect.